# I want to select the same row on the 2nd listview after i select it on the 1st listview in wpf, how can that be done?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, listview, binding

So i have two list views that are related by the first column (TestID). I want the row to be selected automatically on the 2nd listview when i select the row on the 1st listview. This is what i have so far.

```
AutomationTestResults tr = new AutomationTestResults();
    public int SelectedTestID
    {

        get
        {

            return tr.TestID;
        }

        set
        {
            tr.TestID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTestID");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

=============XAML========================================================

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TRCollection }" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestID}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
                  Grid.Row="1" Height="197" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,22,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="680">
        </ListView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TCCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestID}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
                  Grid.Row="1" Height="245" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,251,0,0" Name="listView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="680" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is to select corresponding row in second ListView you can bind "SelectedIndex" property like this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TRCollection }" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestID}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
          Grid.Row="1" Height="197" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,22,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="680"/>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TCCollection}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=listView1}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestID}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
          Grid.Row="1" Height="245" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,251,0,0" Name="listView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="680" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1"/> <!-- etc.. -->

<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listView1}"/>
```

Comment: my listView1 looks like this and it will only get populated when listview2 rows are running...

TestID     Column1
1           asd
2           asd
3           asd

my second listview2 looks like this
TestID          column1      Run
1               bse           1
2               bse           1
3               bse           1

If i use the selected index, then i can run row '3' from listview2 and it will show up as row '1' in listview1. So thats why its better to associated it with the TestID number...but i dont know how to do that :S

Comment: @user2316777 I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm using the `SelectedItem` property, not the `SelectedIndex`. This should work if the Items are the same (that means `Object.Equals() == true`.)